# Why is this WHERE clause killing query performance?

Tags: sql, db2

I have an outer query summarizing the results from three DB2 databases which are housed on an AS400.  The inner union queries run in about 2 minutes.  When I add the outer summary query performance is unaffected.  However, adding a WHERE clause to the outer summary step sends performance to 10+ minutes.  I've killed the query each time since I couldn't understand what was happening.  Any idea why the addition of the WHERE clause would drastically affect performance?  The entire query looks like this (sorry for the pseudo code, the actual query is over 700 lines):

```
SELECT
   field1,
   field2,
   SUM(field3) as my_sum
FROM
   (complex set of three queries with results unioned together from three different databases - runs in about 2 minutes when executed on its own)
WHERE field1 in('string1','string2','string3')
GROUP BY
   field1,
   field2
```

Comment: OS Version? AS400 (DB2 for i) has two optimizers(CQE & SQE).  SQE is more efficient compared to CQE. Minor changes in SQL might switch execution from SQE to CQE.  Older versions of OS use CQE under more conditions compared to new versions.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `WHERE` clause killing performance?

Because it changes the execution plan.  You would need to look at the explain plans for the query.

Why does it change the execution plan?  Because the database gets the idea (the wrong idea in this case) that the additional filtering makes an alternative execution plan better.

What can you do?  Hints are one way to address this issue to get the more optimal plan.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I don't have permission to run explain.  I just need to try and think like an optimizer, or find a way to re-write.

Comment: Most likely field_1 isn't indexed so adding the where statement causes RBAR, right? Can you filter the fields prior to the union using an index on each respective database?

Comment: Field1 is definitely not index since it is the result of a CASE statement within the sub-queries.  The CASE statement is long which is why I want to avoid implementing that down a level.

Comment: @timlash have you tried to run & explain?  Or are you assuming you don't have the authority?  Because I don't know if it's even possible to revoke access to that specifically.  Note that "explain plan" in the IBM i world is invoked by using "Run SQL Scripts" component of Access Client Solutions (ACS) or the older iNav.  There's a button "Run & Explain" or just "Explain" that will show the plan in "Visual Explain"

Comment: You can use use alternative ways to understand optimizer, such as STRDBMON (you will also be fighting with permission but someone in the organization should have authority to execute STRDBMON).

Comment: On the other hand, given that field1 comes from a CASE, IF the criteria on that case are all related to the same table, you can build a derived key index.